# Data verification with openssl smime fails

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography, digital-signature, smime

I am using openssl smime to sign and verify data.

To sign text file using openssl I sue the following command:

> openssl smime -sign -in sample.txt -out mail.msg -signer cert.pem -inkey key.pem

Then I proceed to verification:

> openssl smime -verify -in mail.msg -CAfile allCA.pem

The verification succeed.

My problem is that I have an external tool that performs the verification using the following command:

> openssl smime -verify -in mail.msg -inform DER -CAfile allCA.pem

How to sign my txt file so it can be verified with the previous command ?

**What I've tried so far:**

> openssl smime -sign -in sample.txt -out mail.msg -outform DER -signer cert.pem -inkey key.pem

But I get an error when trying to verify my mail:

```
Verification failure
140204331579208:error:2107507A:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:no content:pk7_smime.c:291:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you call sign operation creates detached signature so you would need to pass `-content sample.txt` to verify command. However, it is possible to create structure that encapsulates message together with signature (`-nodetach` parameter).

This is the sign command you are looking for:

```
openssl smime -sign -in data.dat -out mail.msg -signer cert.pem -inkey key.pem -outform DER -nodetach
```